# Using self signed SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, nginx, go, https, self-signed

I am trying to use this certificate with a connection between an InfluxDB rest endpoint that is behind an nginx reverse-proxy and my simple client written in GoLang.

I started using SSL Certificates generated with openssl using the tutorial found at [this link](http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm) which runs me through creating and self-singing a certificate.

But I get this error every time I try to make this connection:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: invalid signature: parent certificate cannot sign this kind of certificate" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "<My Certificate Name>")
```

I have yet to find a way to get this resolved, but I'll show what I can see as relevant:

As far as I can tell, the nginx rules for InfluxDB were fairly easy to write and ended up looking like this:

```
# InfluxDB
server {
    ssl                   on;
    ssl_protocols         TLSV1.2 TLSV1.1 TLSV1;
    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/server.key;
    listen                8086;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/influxdb.access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/influxdb.error.log;


    location / {
      include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options.conf.inc;
      include /etc/nginx/conf.d/auth.conf.inc;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8087;
    }
  }
```

Where options.conf.inc is:

```
  if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $served_at;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
    add_header Content-Length 0;
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200;
  }
```

Where the auto.conf.inc is:

```
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file <pathTo>.htpasswd;
    error_page 401 /401.html;
```

My golang client looks like this:

```
func main() {
flag.Parse()
// Load client cert
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certFile, keyFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// Load CA cert
caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile(caFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)
// Setup HTTPS client
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    RootCAs:      caCertPool,
    //      InsecureSkipVerify: true,
}
//tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()
transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
// Do GET something
resp, err := client.Get("https://fillerBasicAuthCredentials:password!1@192.168.223.128:8086/query?q=show+databases")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
// Dump response
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Println(string(data))
}
```

As you can see in my golang code, is that I have played with the `InsecureSkipVerify` flag on the tlsConfig object. Setting this to true makes everything work, but seems inherently bad to do since it defeats a lot of the point of using the cert in the first place.

The options I have left, it seems, is to generate a CA cert and use THAT to sign my regular cert, but that also seems like more of a hack than I should be needing to do.

**EDIT (Solution):**

After exploring creating my own CA cert to sign these with I was able to get everything working. Now I have a CA cert that I will use to sign my other certs, and I will be installing this CA cert on the boxes so they know it is a trusted cert.

Pieces that were helpful in how I solved this:

I am using an open source influxdb client that I was trying to avoid using. It currently uses golang's `net/http` package, and not the `crypto` which means I can't specify my CA certs in-code like my example does. I had to install the CA cert onto my box so it was recognized properly. An article I found helpful on this topic is [this one]https://www.happyassassin.net/2015/01/14/trusting-additional-cas-in-fedora-rhel-centos-dont-append-to-etcpkitlscertsca-bundle-crt-or-etcpkitlscert-pem/

Comment: According to the message, it seems you'll have to go the CA cert route to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message is coming from go's [CheckSignatureFrom](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.6/src/crypto/x509/x509.go#L638) method. It looks like it requires the CA flag in `basicConstraints` to be set to true, and if the `keyUsage` field is present (it is in the example you linked but it's not in most instructions I've seen for using self-signed certs) it must include the `keyCertSign` value.

When I've faced similar problems I've created a CA that is separate from the server certificate. It's a little more work, but it's not a "hack"; if anything setting up the self-signed cert to be properly recognized as its own CA is the hackier solution.

Comment: I was able to get everything working cleanly by generating a second cert that I will use as my CA cert. I have edited my question to include some other details. Thank you.